# how to insert new value into max heap and apply max_delete to heap

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap, heapsort, binary-heap

*Problem 1*

```
                     98
                    /  \
                   /    \
                 67      89
                / \     /  \
               /   \   /    \
             38   42  54    89
            / \
           /   \
          17   25
```

i want to insert 97 into max heap [98,67,89,38,42,54,89,17,25] (represented in list).

As per me, resulting heap is [98,97,89,38,67,54,89,17,25,42]

```
                     98
                    /  \
                   /    \
                 97      89
                / \     /  \
               /   \   /    \
             38    67  54    89
            / \     |
           /   \    |
          17   25   42
```

*Problem 2*

i want to apply delete_max() twice to the heap [100,97,93,38,67,54,93,17,25,42].

```
                    100
                    /  \
                   /    \
                 97      93
                / \     /  \
               /   \   /    \
             38    67  54    93
            / \     |
           /   \    |
          17   25   42
```

As per me heap after two deletemax operations,resulting heap is [93,67,93,38,42,54,25,17]

```
                     93
                    /  \
                   /    \
                 67      93
                / \     /  \
               /   \   /    \
             38    42  54    25
            /     
           /      
          17
```

**I want to conform, is I am doing insertion and max_delete correctly for heap and above answer is correct?**
If not correct, then please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers look correct. Let's take a closer look at why.

In the first case, you have the heap:

```
[98,67,89,38,42,54,89,17,25]
```

You want to insert 97. So you add it to the end and then bubble it up:

```
[98,67,89,38,42,54,89,17,25,97]
```

You compare 97 with its parent (42). Since 97 is greater, you swap them:

```
[98,67,89,38,97,54,89,17,25,42]
```

Then compare 97 with its parent again. This time the parent is 67, so you have to swap again.

```
[98,97,89,38,67,54,89,17,25,42]
```

Comparing one more time, you see that the parent (98) is greater than the item you inserted, so you're done.

Now, given the heap `[100,97,93,38,67,54,93,17,25,42]`, you want to remove the two highest items. The rule for delete_max is replace the root with the last item on the heap, and then sift it down. So you have:

```
 [42,97,93,38,67,54,93,17,25]
```

42 is smaller than its children, so you swap it with the largest child:

```
 [97,42,93,38,67,54,93,17,25]
```

It's greater than 38, but smaller than 67, so you swap again:

```
 [97,67,93,38,42,54,93,17,25]
```

And 42 is now at the leaf level so there's nothing more to do. That's the first item removed. Now to remove the second. Move 25 to the root:

```
 [25,67,93,38,42,54,93,17]
```

And sifting down:

```
[93,67,25,38,42,54,93,17]  // swapped with 93
[93,67,93,38,42,54,25,17]  // swapped with 93 again
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for this link so you can access by this link

https://cstechwiki.blogspot.in/2016/09/python-week-6-quiz-assignment-nptel.html

Comment: Please consider adding more details to your post.  In the event that your links change or become unavailable, your answer will not be helpful.